# When to use YOLO vs vanilla CNN?

Tags: tensorflow, keras, conv-neural-network, yolo

I am wanting to build a computer vision model that can identify an object in an image. For example, identify the (x, y, width, height) pixel coordinates of the bounding box of somebody's hand. I know of complex object detection algorithm likes YOLO and RCNN but am curious as to why I couldn't just create a vanilla Conv Net with an output layer of 4 neurons (for each coordinate value) w/ linear activation functions?

For clarity, I am not wanting to identify **multiple objects** in the image. Just assuming that only one hand is present in each image.

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Sure you can, you are comparing algorithms for completely different problems.

Comment: @Dr.Snoopy I would say single object detection vs multiple object detection is not COMPLETELY different...

Comment: It is, single object detection (called object localization actually) is a much simpler problem than object detection, where objects might or might not be present, and in multiple variable quantities.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You for sure can do it, there's no math stopping you or anything. YOLO is designed for multiple objects after all.

Some thoughts though:

- Your model will always guess some box, even when there's no hand in the image.
- If you do use YOLO, you gain the benefit of using some pre-trained network, which makes it robust (at least more robust) to using the model in new environments.